# Grabbing the value of the parent key when using a foreach loop on an object in PHP?

Tags: php, object, foreach

So this is a bit goofy, but I need this for a logic gate. I have an object, that when dumped, looks like so:

```
object(stdClass)#925 (5) { 
  ["31"]=> object(stdClass)#1180 (4) { ["price"]=> string(3) "6.5" ["finalPrice"]=> string(3) "6.5" ["tierpricing"]=> string(1) "0" ["has_image"]=> bool(true) }
  ["32"]=> object(stdClass)#1174 (4) { ["price"]=> string(4) "10.5" ["finalPrice"]=> string(4) "10.5" ["tierpricing"]=> string(1) "0" ["has_image"]=> bool(true) } 
  ["36"]=> object(stdClass)#1331 (4) { ["price"]=> string(4) "18.5" ["finalPrice"]=> string(4) "18.5" ["tierpricing"]=> string(1) "0" ["has_image"]=> bool(true) } 
  ["255"]=> object(stdClass)#1094 (4) { ["price"]=> string(4) "23.5" ["finalPrice"]=> string(4) "23.5" ["tierpricing"]=> string(1) "0" ["has_image"]=> bool(true) } 
  ["1066"]=> object(stdClass)#1117 (4) { ["price"]=> string(5) "84.95" ["finalPrice"]=> string(5) "84.95" ["tierpricing"]=> string(1) "0" ["has_image"]=> bool(true) } 
}
```

I then need to loop through with a foreach loop, where my var_dump now will look like so:

```
object(stdClass)#1180 (4) { ["price"]=> string(3) "6.5" ["finalPrice"]=> string(3) "6.5" ["tierpricing"]=> string(1) "0" ["has_image"]=> bool(true) }
object(stdClass)#1174 (4) { ["price"]=> string(4) "10.5" ["finalPrice"]=> string(4) "10.5" ["tierpricing"]=> string(1) "0" ["has_image"]=> bool(true) }
object(stdClass)#1331 (4) { ["price"]=> string(4) "18.5" ["finalPrice"]=> string(4) "18.5" ["tierpricing"]=> string(1) "0" ["has_image"]=> bool(true) }
object(stdClass)#1094 (4) { ["price"]=> string(4) "23.5" ["finalPrice"]=> string(4) "23.5" ["tierpricing"]=> string(1) "0" ["has_image"]=> bool(true) }
object(stdClass)#1117 (4) { ["price"]=> string(5) "84.95" ["finalPrice"]=> string(5) "84.95" ["tierpricing"]=> string(1) "0" ["has_image"]=> bool(true) }
```

This is, of course, respective, and I'm trying to see if I can grab onto those parent values (31, 32, 36, 255, 1066) while in the foreach iteration. Is this possible in anyway?

Comment: `foreach($obj as $key=>$data){}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those values  you are looking for are the keys. Try with:

```
foreach ($yourData as $key => $object) {
  var_dump($key);
  var_dump($object);
}
```

Comment: Wonderful. That works perfectly. Sorry about the duplicate to everyone out there, I suppose I didn't know what to search to find this. Thanks @hsz!